# Python Pillow: how to overlay one binary image on top of another to produce a composite?

Tags: python, image, python-imaging-library

I am doing some image processing, and I need to check if a binary image is identical to another.

Processing speed isn't an issue, and the simple thing I thought to do was count the white pixels remaining after adding the inverse of image A to image B (these images are very nearly identical, but not quite--some sort of distance metric is the goal).

- Note: take the logarithm to linearize the distance

However, in order to create the composite image, I need to include a "mask" that is the same size as the two images.

I am having trouble finding an example of creating the mask online and using it for the Image.composite function.

Here is my code:

```
compA = ImageOps.invert(imgA)
imgAB = Image.composite(compA,imgB,??? mask)
```

Right now, I have created a mask of all zeros--however, the composite image does not appear correctly (both A and B are exactly the same images; a mask of all zeros--or all ones for that matter--does not work).

```
mask = Image.fromarray(np.zeros(imgA.size,dtype=int),mode='L')
imgAB = Image.composite(compA,imgB,mask)
```

How do I just add these two binary images on top of eachother?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Clearly you're using `numpy`, so why not just work with `numpy` arrays and explicitly do whatever arithmetic you want to do in that domain—such as subtracting one image from the other:

```
arrayA = numpy.asarray( imgA, dtype=int )
arrayB = numpy.asarray( imgB, dtype=int )

arrayDelta = arrayA - arrayB

print( (arrayDelta !=0 ).sum() )  # print the number of non-identical pixels (why count them by hand?)
# NB: this number may be inflated by a factor of 3 if there are 3 identical channels R, G, B

imgDelta = Image.fromarray((numpy.sign(arrayDelta)*127+127).astype('uint8'))  # display this image if you want to visualize where the differences are
```

You could do this even more simply, e.g.

```
print((numpy.asarray(imgA) != numpy.asarray(imgB)).sum())
```

but I thought casting to a signed integer type first and then subtracting would allow you to visualize more information (A white and B black -> white pixel in delta; A black and B white -> black pixel in delta)

Comment: Ok, I think it works.  However, the images of the np arrays, when I convert them back don't seem to have all the pixels...

To view them, I run: `Image.fromarray(arrayA,mode='L').show()`; my first set of images is the white outline of a box on a black background--not filled in...but a visualization of the first image, after numpy conversion, yields a vertically striped white box in a black background, filled in.

Comment: Try `Image.fromarray(arrayA.astype('uint8'), mode='L')`